# What's the best way to integrate Designers using Dreamweaver with Visual Studio C# developers?

Tags: c#, dreamweaver

I know about code-behind files, but what is the best real-world way of Designers that are using DreamWeaver or other Design Tools to work with Visual Studio programmers?

For example, say you have a basic website with user interface forms hitting the database... the database work is definitely done by the developer but how to tie the designed forms with the database coding or client-side logic that may involve events on controls, or other GUI related tie-ins.  Are the graphic designers also controlling application flow?  There seems to be a large disconnect that needs addressed - especially when it comes time to tweak the design after it's been implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use another approach like [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller), separate your design from your logic. Like this every member (designer / developer) of the team can focus on what they do best.

MVC implementations: [link](http://www.asp.net/mvc/) / [link](http://www.castleproject.org/monorail/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to make sure that your designers have some knowledge of what kind of HTML they will be working with.

Every ASP.NET developer is aware of MS-HTML, that lovely nesting of HTML tables, but designers aren't. Designers have their own requirements to meet and they'll do them in the best manner possible. Sadly it's not often good for us.

I am always frustrated when I receive a design from our UI team which shows radio-buttons nicely layed out in a grid using floating div's. Then I have to shatter their dreams that no, I can't generate you that HTML (ok, I can with the use of ControlAdapters, but every time they are different designs!).

Try and have a 90%/ 10% rule, where 90% of the design is done before the ASP.NET starts and the 10% is done once the ASP.NET is completed, and done against ASP.NET generated HTML.

And make sure you're using source control! Code doesn't exist unless it's in source control! And thanks to the latest TFS PowerTools there's a lovely Windows Shell integration component so you don't need to use VS to check in and out now more :D

Comment: But what about changes after it's been rolled out?  Are they expected to keep the control naming conventions for example?  Usually they end up giving a brand new design that has to be re-implemented after every change.

Comment: Updated designs (not reskins) should always be done off the existing HTML/ CSS base so it shouldn't be a problem to refactor.

If you wanted to be really careful you could have the HTML/ CSS updated at go-live to meet the generated ASP.NET stuff.

Answer (score 1):

This may sound really cheezy, but when I was working with Dreamweaver / Visual Studio, I'd do my layouts, and then conveniently put [RADIO BUTTON HERE], [INPUT TEXT HERE], etc. in the places where my form elements/controls would go, and I'd save the page as a basic HTML document.

That way Dreamweaver wouldn't nest its own form tags in and I'd have easy to locate places to drop in my ASP.NET controls when I went to merge things in. It was easy enough to create a fresh web form page in Visual Studio and then copy and paste everything over. If for some reason I mucked things up, I'd have a basic HTML "template" to start over wtih.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is an all too common problem. Dreamweaver typically doesn't write html that is friendly to a .net developer. If at all possible, get someone who can actually read, and write HTML,not just use the Dreamweaver WYSIWYG editor.

I often found that if I'm working with a designer that doesn't know html, that I actually save a lot of time be just having them mock up everything in photoshop, then give me sliced up images. I find that my writing the actual HTML in a .net friendly format saves a ton of time, instead of having to go back and forth with the designer in this situation.